# XSD Restriction for 1 or more day of week

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I'm trying to use a pattern match for an element coming in to me that lists 1 to 7 of the shortnames for the day of week.  I tried creating one pattern in an online tool that matched there, but fails when in the XSD and validated.

Sample ways elements can come in.

```
<DayOfWeek>Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun </DayOfWeek>
<DayOfWeek>Mon Wed Fri </DayOfWeek>
```

I used http://www.regexpal.com/ to help create the following regex pattern.  I tried using the following which work on the site:

```
(Mon)?(Tue)?(Wed)?(Thu)?(Fri)?(Sat)?(Sun)?[ ]+
(Mon[ ]+)?(Tue[ ]+)?(Wed[ ]+)?(Thu[ ]+)?(Fri[ ]+)?(Sat[ ]+)?(Sun[ ]+)?
```

When applied in the following simpleType:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ValidDays">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:pattern value="(Mon[ ]+)?(Tue[ ]+)?(Wed[ ]+)?(Thu[ ]+)?(Fri[ ]+)?(Sat[ ]+)?(Sun[ ]+)?" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And referenced for the element in the XSD here:

```
<xs:element name="DayOfWeek">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="ValidDays" />
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```

it fails with this message for either pattern restriction:

```
The 'DayOfWeek' element is invalid - The value 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun ' is invalid according to its datatype 'Token' - The Pattern constraint failed.
```

I even tried applying the '/' and '/g' from the site, just in case, and I get the same fail message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xs:list` rather than regex for space-delimited lists of enumerated values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="DayOfWeek">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:list itemType="ValidDays"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="ValidDays">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Sun"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Mon"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Tue"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Wed"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Thu"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Fri"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Sat"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, handled what needed to be checked and error'd out for any misspelling, accidental use of lower case, but allows 1 or more blanks.  I can now use this to also replace a regex for acceptable multiple hour numbers that I didn't like, it didn't feel solid enough.